# Reading Csv File using Pandas But i need compare Case Sensitive Data between two data frames

Tags: pandas, case-sensitive

is there is any solution to Handle Case Sensitive Data between two dataframes without converting to upper or lower cases in pandas?

Thank you

I'm reading the  two different csv files using pandas i.e (df1,df2)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(first_file, header=0, on_bad_lines="skip", index_col=index_column)

df2 = pd.read_csv(second_file, header=0, on_bad_lines="skip", index_col=index_column)
```

and comparing data between two data frames but i'm getting the case sensitive difference between them but i didn't want to compare case sensitive data i want to ignore case sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `str.casefold()` method.

```
df1['col_name'] = df1['col_name'].str.casefold()
df2['col_name'] = df2['col_name'].str.casefold()

result = df1.equals(df2)
```

You can try this with the actual column names.